# Coefficients of Knuth's "Convolution Polynomials"

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, convolution, coefficients

Donald E. Knuth gives in his paper [Convolution Polynomials](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9207221) the code

```
F[n_, x_] := Sum[f[n, j] x^j, {j, 0, n}]/n!
conv[n_] := LogicalExpand[Series[F[n, x + y], {x, 0, n}, {y, 0, n}]
== Series[Sum[F[k, x] F[n - k, y], {k, 0, n}], {x, 0, n}, {y, 0, n}]]
Solve[Table[conv[n], {n, 0, 4}], [Flatten[Table[f[i, j], {i, 0, 4},{j, 0, 4}]]]]
```

and then writes: "*Mathematica* replies that the $F$'s are either 
identically zero or the coefficients of $F_n(x)$ satisfy ..."
How can I get the table following this statement?

Comment: Try fixing the syntax (typo): There a `[` in front of `Flatten` and an extra `]` at the end that should be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Michael notes, deleting the stray brackets will make it work. A better method, however, would be to use `SolveAlways[]`:

```
F[n_, x_] := Sum[f[n, j]x^j, {j, 0, n}]/n!
SolveAlways[Table[Series[F[n, x + y], {x, 0, n}, {y, 0, n}] ==
                  Series[Sum[F[k, x]F[n - k, y], {k, 0, n}], {x, 0, n}, {y, 0, n}],
                  {n, 0, 4}], {x, y}][[1]]
   {f[4, 4] -> f[1, 1]^4, f[4, 0] -> 0, f[4, 2] -> 3 f[2, 1]^2 + 4 f[1, 1] f[3, 1],
    f[4, 3] -> 6 f[1, 1]^2 f[2, 1], f[3, 3] -> f[1, 1]^3, f[3, 0] -> 0,
    f[3, 2] -> 3 f[1, 1] f[2, 1], f[2, 2] -> f[1, 1]^2, f[2, 0] -> 0, f[0, 0] -> 1,
    f[1, 0] -> 0}
```